# Concatenate lists to list within for loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop, python-3.x, concatenation

Aim it to concatenate multiple lists to one list within a for loop. At the moment the output prints map objects rather than all the content merged in one list.

**Directory**

[image]

**Content of each sample file**

```
aa - http://cc
bb - http://bb
cc - http://aa
aa - aa - http://cc
bb - bb - http://bb
cc - cc - http://aa
aa - aa - aa - http://cc
bb - bb - bb - http://bb
cc - cc - cc - http://aa
```

**Code**

```
import os

cwd = os.getcwd()

for fn in os.listdir(cwd):
    with open(fn, "r+") as f, open(cwd + "\\all.txt", "r+") as f2:
        lines = f.readlines()

        my_list = [fn + " - " + x for x in lines]

        concatenated_list = map(" ".join, zip(my_list))
        print(concatenated_list)
```

**Outcome**

*Current*

```
C:\case.py
<map object at 0x0000000002CB7BE0>
<map object at 0x0000000002CB7B00>
<map object at 0x0000000002CB79E8>
<map object at 0x0000000002CB7E10>
<map object at 0x0000000002CB7A90>
<map object at 0x0000000002CB78D0>
```

*Expected*

```
C:\Users\r\Desktop\test>C:\Users\r\Desktop\case.py
[]
['sample.txt - aa - http://cc\n', 'sample.txt - bb - http://bb\n', 'sample.txt -
 cc - http://aa\n', 'sample.txt - aa - aa - http://cc\n', 'sample.txt - bb - bb
- http://bb\n', 'sample.txt - cc - cc - http://aa\n', 'sample.txt - aa - aa - aa
 - http://cc\n', 'sample.txt - bb - bb - bb - http://bb\n', 'sample.txt - cc - c
c - cc - http://aa\n','sample2.txt - aa - http://cc\n', 'sample2.txt - bb - http://bb\n', 'sample2.tx
t - cc - http://aa\n', 'sample2.txt - aa - aa - http://cc\n', 'sample2.txt - bb
- bb - http://bb\n', 'sample2.txt - cc - cc - http://aa\n', 'sample2.txt - aa -
aa - aa - http://cc\n', 'sample2.txt - bb - bb - bb - http://bb\n', 'sample2.txt
 - cc - cc - cc - http://aa\n'...
```

Comment: I may not be understanding what you're doing, but it sure looks to me like the `zip`, `join` and `map` calls are all completely unnecessary. Get rid of them all and just use `print(my_list)` and you'll get the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 3.x, `map()` returns an iterator, not a list. Try this instead:

```
concatenated_list = []
# Then in your for loop...
  concatenated_list += [" ".join(x) for x in zip(my_list)]
```

The `+=` will concatenate all of the lists together.

Also don't overload the `list` keyword. You don't want to overwrite the name of a built-in function. If you used the method in Padraic's answer, it would fail because Python thinks you're trying to call your `list` as a function, instead of the builtin `list()` function.

Comment: The lists are still separated `C:\>C:\case.py
[]
['sample.txt - aa - http://cc\n', 'sample.txt - bb - http://bb\n', 'sample.txt -
 cc - http://aa\n', 'sample.txt - aa - aa - http://cc\n', 'sample.txt - bb - bb
- http://bb\n', 'sample.txt - cc - cc - http://aa\n', 'sample.txt - aa - aa - aa
 - http://cc\n', 'sample.txt - bb - bb - bb - http://bb\n', 'sample.txt - cc - c
c - cc - http://aa']
['sample2.txt - aa - http://cc\n', 'sample2.txt - bb - http://bb\n', 'sample2.tx
t - cc - http://aa\n', 'sample2.txt - aa - aa - http://cc\n', 'sample2.txt - bb
- bb - `

Comment: To turn something into a list, you can simply use `list(...)` -- no need for the awkward `[x for x in ...]`.  In this particular case, you could also replace the `map()` call by a list comprehension:  `[" ".join(x) for x in zip(my_list)]`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach I figured it could be simplified, but wasn't 100% sure what he was doing so I didn't want to replace something that seemed to be working alright. I've edited my answer with your suggestion though. Thanks!

Comment: Final code: `import os

cwd = os.getcwd()
concatenated_list = []

for fn in os.listdir(cwd):
    with open(fn, "r+") as f, open(cwd + "\\all.txt", "r+") as f2:
        lines = f.readlines()

        my_list = [fn + " - " + x for x in lines]

        concatenated_list += [" ".join(x) for x in zip(my_list)]

        lines = sorted(concatenated_list, key=lambda text: text.rsplit('-', 1)[::-1])

        f2.write("\n".join(lines))`

Answer (score 1):

Use `list(concatenated_list)`  `map` and `zip` are iterators in `python3` , also don't use list as a variable name it shadows the builtin `list`

```
           my_list =  [fn + " - " + x for x in lines]
           concatenated_list = map(" ".join, [x for x in zip(my_list)])
           print (list(concatenated_list))
```

Answer (score -1):

concatenated_list = list(map(" ".join, zip(my_list)))
I agree with Padraic, put list in front of map